# linux-mint Font size increased to a large size, now every window garbels display

Tags: linux, fonts, gnome, linux-mint

Hey guys I have made a blunder. While i was playing with cinnamon settings I set the font size to 990 from the font icon available in cinnamon settings. Now I cant use any applications because of the font. It garbeles the whole screen. I cannot redo it cos when i somehow manage to open cinnamon settings I cant see the font icon, because of the font size and I even if i maximize that window I cant see the font icon. I can see up to icon themes that's it. Now what to do, Is there any way of setting things to normal. I tried setting cinnamon settings to default but did not work. Now what to do? Is it possible from terminal?

Comment: any answers? does someone know where to ask help apart from SO

Comment: This question would be better posed at SuperUser. PS. Addressing your question to "guys" might make women feel unwelcome to answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can change Cinnamon/Gnome settings from terminal using **gsettings** command. You will need to know the schema and key for the setting you want to change. For instance, to change the titlebar font:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences titlebar-font 'Sans 10'
```

You can also inspect values by changing "set" to "get" and omitting value parameter like so:

```
gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences titlebar-font
```

Most changes via gsettings (including UI fonts) are reflected immediately; however, a few may require relogin. I recommend full relogin over Cinnamon restart because changes via gsettings and restart don't always play well together (sometimes resulting in cosmetic glitches...apps disappearing from panel and so on).